# Update .html files to add div content from xml file in Batch

Tags: xml, batch-file

So I have folder full of html files with for each tables of a database (auto-generated)...

```
table/table1.html
table/table2.html
...
table/table200.html
```

I have an xml file with the following data...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tables>
    <table1>This is the table1 table description.</table1>
    <table2>This is the table2 table description.</table2>
    ...
    <table200>This is the table200 table description.</table200>
</tables>
```

I was hoping to create a batch file that will read this xml and replace `<div id="maintabs">` to `<div id="tabledesc>This is the tableN table description we get from xml.</div><div id="maintabs">`.

I am able to do it individually with [FART](http://fart-it.sourceforge.net/) and [xml.exe](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html), but I can't seem to get it to work dynamically and use the values generated from xml.exe

Any help will be much appreciated.

Just to be clear, my requirement is table1.html file should be modified to add the table table1 data from the xml file, table2.html with the table2 tag data, and so on.

Comment: Do you really want to use a batch file for this? It's about 15 lines in Python/Ruby/Perl.

Comment: @NickBailey - I can mange with the Python/ Perl alternative. But  I have no knowledge of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you're manipulating or extracting data from XML or HTML, it's generally preferable to parse it as XML or HTML, rather than trying to scrape bits of text from it. Regardless of whether your XML is beautified or minified, if you parse XML as XML, your code still works. The same can't be said for regexp or token searches.

Pure batch doesn't handle XML and HTML DOM all that well. But Windows Scripting Host does -- XML with the `Microsoft.XMLDOM` COM object, and HTML with the scantily-documented `htmlfile` COM object.

Anyway, challenge: accepted.  Save this with a .bat extension, salt to taste, and run it.  It's a batch + JScript hybrid script.  It uses an XPath query to get the data from the `tableN` element of your XML file matching the basename of the HTML file (see the `selectSingleNode('//' + basename + '/text()')` line toward the bottom); then uses JavaScript-ish `element.insertBefore` to insert a new DIV containing that data into the HTML DOM before saving the change the target html file.

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
setlocal

set "xmlfile=test.xml"
set "htmlfolder=table\"

for %%I in ("%htmlfolder%\*.html") do cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" "%xmlfile%" "%%~fI"

rem // end main runtime
goto :EOF

@end
// end batch / begin JScript chimera

var XMLDOM = WSH.CreateObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM'),
    HTMLDOM = WSH.CreateObject('htmlfile'),
    fso = WSH.CreateObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject'),
    htmlfile = fso.OpenTextFile(WSH.Arguments(1), 1),
    html = htmlfile.ReadAll(),
    htmltag = html.replace(/\r?\n/g,'').match(/<html.*?>/i)[0] + '\r\n',
    doctype = /<!doctype/i.test(html) ? html.split(/<html/i)[0] : '',
    target = WSH.Arguments(1).replace(/.*\\/, ''),
    basename = target.split('.')[0];

HTMLDOM.write(html);
htmlfile.Close();

if (HTMLDOM.getElementById('tabledesc')) {
    WSH.Echo(target + ' already modified.');
    WSH.Quit(0);
} else WSH.StdOut.Write('processing ' + target + '... ');

with (XMLDOM) {
    load(WSH.Arguments(0));
    async = false;
    setProperty('SelectionLanguage', 'XPath');
}

if (XMLDOM.parseError.errorCode) {
   WSH.Echo(XMLDOM.parseError.reason);
   WSH.Quit(1);
}

var tabledesc = HTMLDOM.createElement('div'),
    XMLnode = XMLDOM.documentElement.selectSingleNode('//' + basename + '/text()');

if (!XMLnode) {
    WSH.Echo('no XML data.');
    WSH.Quit(0);
}

with (tabledesc) {
    id = 'tabledesc';
    innerHTML = XMLnode.data;
}

var htmlfile = fso.CreateTextFile(WSH.Arguments(1), true),
    maintabs = HTMLDOM.getElementById('maintabs');

maintabs.parentNode.insertBefore(tabledesc, maintabs);

htmlfile.write(doctype + htmltag + HTMLDOM.documentElement.innerHTML + '\r\n</html>');
htmlfile.Close();

WSH.Echo('Done.');
```

Comment: Getting and error `D:\Work\Test\so.bat(22, 5) Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'html.replace(...).match(...).0' is null or not an object`

Comment: Do your HTML files not include an `<html>` tag?  Or does the directory contain files other than tableNNN.html?  You might want to change the `for` loop near the top to specify `for %%I in ("%htmlfolder%\*.html")`.

Comment: Oh...after adding <html> tags it worked like a charm, but I saw table1 hardcoded.... so is it not recursive from the xml

Comment: Oh, I see.  So table1.html gets its data from `<table1>data</table1>`, table2.html from `<table2>data</table2>` and so on?  I think I can make it more dynamic.  Edit forthcoming.

Comment: So `<div id="maintabs">` gets converted to `<DIV id=maintabs>` infact in all divs quotes  get removed... will that be a problem ?

Comment: No.  That's just how the Internet Explorer engine interprets the tags in its DOM.  Code edited.  Try the update please.  I also edited your question to make it clearer what you are asking (I hope).  If I have misunderstood the request, feel free to revert the changes.

Comment: So it works great but.... if in the input xml the table desc is missing say `<table22>` then after processing `table22.html` becomes empty.

Comment: Fine.  I added a check for XML data before overwriting the target HTML file.